# What can we return as an "NaN" when writing template algorithm for "most frequent value"?

Tags: c++, algorithm, templates, stl

I write a simple template function for range-based and container-based search of the "most frequent value", but to be really '*generic*' I'm wondering what I should return if the container or the range is empty. In the 1st draft below I used **numeric_limits** to return **quiet_NaN** or **signaling_NaN**, but if the **std::iterator_traits::value_type** is *string* ... is a default CTOR a good idea or good pratice ?

```
struct comp_by_second
{
  template <typename Pair>
  bool operator()(const Pair& a, const Pair& b)
  {
    return a.second < b.second;
  }
};

template <typename Fwd>
typename std::iterator_traits<Fwd>::value_type  most_frequent_element(Fwd begin, Fwd end)
{
std::map<typename std::iterator_traits<Fwd>::value_type, int> count;
for (Fwd it = begin; it != end; ++it)
  ++count[*it];

if(count.size() == 0) {
  if(std::numeric_limits<typename std::iterator_traits<Fwd>::value_type >::has_quiet_NaN)
    return std::numeric_limits<typename std::iterator_traits<Fwd>::value_type>::quiet_NaN();
  else {
    if(std::numeric_limits<typename std::iterator_traits<Fwd>::value_type >::has_signaling_NaN)
      return std::numeric_limits<typename std::iterator_traits<Fwd>::value_type>::signaling_NaN();
    else {
      return std::iterator_traits<Fwd>::value_type () /*default CTOR similar to uninitialized ... ??? */;
    }
  }
}
else 
  return (*std::max_element(count.begin(), count.end(), comp_by_second())).first;
}

template <typename C>
typename std::iterator_traits<typename C::iterator>::value_type  most_frequent_element(const C& container)
{
 return most_frequent_element(container.begin(), container.end());
}
```

Comment: Why not throw an exception in this case?

Comment: If there is no sensible value to return, you should throw an exception. An alternative is to modify your API such that it returns iterators rather than values. You then can return the end of the input range.

Comment: `boost::optional` or `std::experimental::optional`?

Comment: Hi, thank you all for those good advice, I finally choose to keep an STL-like approach as I didn't want to have a dependency on boost in that piece of code, so finally if there is 'no' Most Frequent Value, in case of empty range, I return the last(end) iterator.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your allowed input range does not cover all possible values of your data type (for example, if your data type is float and you *know* that NaNs are not allowed), then you can choose such a "non-allowed" value and return it in case the container is empty.

However, if there is no such a non-allowed value, as is the case for a really generic template function, this strategy is impossible. Note that even your returning NaN is not quite correct, because you actually *can* have a container full of NaNs, why not?.. In this case you should use some special way of returning "no value". This is actually exactly what [boost::optional](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/libs/optional/doc/html/index.html) was made for. In particular, see its [Motivation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/libs/optional/doc/html/optional/tutorial.html#boost_optional.tutorial.motivation) for the discussion of different approaches.

Comment: +1. Returning a specific value of the same type as success in the event of failure which is not a dedicated value is tremendously bad design.

Answer (score -1):

Another fully generic option is to take an extra parameter, whose value you will return in the event that the range provided is empty.  This essentially delegates the responsibility to the caller.  You could even make this a default parameter, to simplify calls in common cases where the caller knows that the range is non-empty.  For maximum flexibility, you can use a traits class template for this:

```
template <typename T>
struct invalid_value_for
{
    static const T value = T();    // Default to default-constructed T instance
};

template <typename T>
static const invalid_value_for<T>::value;    // We also need the definition

// You can "override" this default for specific types with specialisations:
template <>
struct invalid_value_for<int>
{
    static const int value = 42;    // Probably not a good choice, but you get the idea
};

static const invalid_value_for<int>::value;    // We also need the definition

...

template <typename Fwd>
typename std::iterator_traits<Fwd>::value_type most_frequent_element(
    Fwd begin,
    Fwd end,
    typename std::iterator_traits<Fwd>::value_type invalid_value =
        invalid_value_for<typename std::iterator_traits<Fwd>::value_type>::value)
{
```

(Unfortunately it seems to be illegal to make default parameters refer back to the value of earlier parameters, otherwise you could instead set the default value to `*begin`.)

Comment: This makes the tremendously bad mistake of assuming that a particular iterator or element type always has a pre-reserved "invalid value" value, which would be a terrible idea. Furthermore, the key here is not just to return some T, it's to actually signal failure, in which case the user should not be able to pretend that it succeeded, at which you failed utterly. In short, this fails to achieve even the most basic goals of error handling and does so in an awful fashion.

Comment: @Puppy: While you're right to suggest that it's poor design to assume that every type has an "invalid value", this is easily overcome: just leave the base template for `invalid_value_for<T>` without a `value` member, forcing the user to specialise (and thereby assume responsibility for) any type they *do* wish to use default parameters with, on pain of compile-time error.  The other problem is your unwarranted (and bizarrely impassioned) insistence that having no value to return must constitute an error.  There's no reason we can't tweak the semantics -- c.f. `foldl` vs. `foldl1` in Haskell.